# Dead GFCI Outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have 4 GFCI receptacles in my kitchen that are not working. All appear to be on the same breaker. I immediately checked to see if I could reset them and could not. So next I checked the breakers in my main box. None of them were tripped but still I turned them fully off and back on just to be sure and still, no power going to my receptacles.

My next step was to check the breakers with a multimeter, they came back showing 120 V. I tried chasing these wires throughout my basement and it didn't appear that any of the wires went into a junction box. I took all 4 outlets out of the wall and checked the wires going into them, all of which were cold.

My initial thought was it has to be somewhere between the breaker and the receptacle, but if anyone else has an idea, I will definitely try it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Did these receptacles suddenly stop working, or gradually, or what? Was there any event which precipitated them not working? Are there any outlets downstream of the GFCIs that are protected? Do they work or not?

Comment: my suspicion would be that there is one or more GFCI recpts on the circuit somewhere.  Something tripped them all. If this is the case, they will need to be reset in order from the panel because a GFCI that has no power feed will not reset.   If this is case, they could be rewired so that they are not daisy chained.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome.They just stopped working suddenly,  My wife was the one who noticed it first, she said when she went to plug the toaster in that morning that none of them worked.   Not sure if this is worth mentioning but there are other receptacles in the kitchen that's  connected to a different breaker, those are working.In the breaker box there are two different breakers one is labelled "east kitchen receptacle" and " south kitchen receptacle" Will I know which order they are in by the green light coming on or not? i've tried resetting them all but not in a particular order

Comment: If they are mis-wired so that they are wired from the load terminals of the prior GFCI in the circuit they will have to be reset in the order they come from the panel. If none will reset, then there is likely one more someplace that you haven't found yet.  It's a fairly common residential wiring mess-up, not unsafe but very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out which breaker these GFCIs are on and turn it off. Then search for any other dead outlets. If you find one, that's probably where the junction is. If not, start pulling outlets and switches out until you find some wires that are spliced and just pass through the box. Check those connections. Pigtail anything you find that's using an outlet as an in/out, especially if they used backstabs.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the lost junction box in the basement, hiding in between a floor joist.  There are 5 hot wires spliced into each other and wrapped in electrical tape, the main hot wire coming from the breaker box wasn't fully wrapped around the others and appears to have wiggled loose some how. Using a multi meter i tested each wire and only one was hot.   I killed the power,  cleaned the wire, trimmed the excess and used a big wire nut along with some more electrical tape and now I'm back in action.   Thanks again!  I really appreciate the helpful posts

Answer (score 0):

did they wire the receptacles in series or parallel? if in series all it takes is one to fail and rest will stop or sounds like in this case the wire failed somewhere in between. if you have power at breaker and nothing at outlet definitely a broken wire either the hot leg or neutral